# intent from marker info window

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to open an activity on android´s app clicking map marker´s info window info info but I can´t, here is my code:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                          OtherActivity.class);
                     in.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());


                }
            });
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Create a `Handler` and put your `Intent` on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know where can I find an example code? :-)

Comment: ya off course. see my answer. it's working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to start `Activity` like

```
 Youractivity.this.startActivity(in);
```

and try another way

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    Message mesg = new Message();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("title", marker.getTitle());
    mesg.setData(b);
    handler.sendMessage(mesg);

      }
   });
```

Now create `Handler` for that like so.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();
        Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("title", b.getString("title"));
        Youractivity.this.startActivity(in);
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, I forget start the activity, I am stupid… thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that it is not starting because you didnt start the activity using the `startActivity` method of the UI thread.

**solution:**

```
MyActivity.this.startActivity(in);
```